# Display Loader untill the browser loading icon is rotating

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a page which contains heavy traffic . It  is fetching data from multiple servers and showing in the page . It takes usually 3-4 minutes for the page to complete the loading . Please take a look at some of the partial page data

[image]

All i need is a spinning gif or a loader to get over the page so that user can't click any link unless the page gets loaded completely .

I have tried the following code

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript"  src="JavaScript/jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
<script>
hideLoading = function() {
    $('.loading').fadeOut(20000, function() {
        $(".content").fadeIn(10000);        
    });
};
hideLoading();
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<body>
<div class="loading">Loading...</div>
<div class="content">
```

The problem is when user reloads the page the browser loader spins but the content in the page doesn't get my loader to get over the content . 
It only happens until the DOM gets loaded .

All I want is to get the loader to work as soon as user clicks the reload icon or hits enter or F5 or ctrl+f5 for page reload . Hope i made myself clear.

Answer (score 0):

Place your jquery code in document.ready function and make some delay on that function like following :-

Add this jquery code at bottom of page.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    hideLoading = function() {
        $('.loading').fadeOut(20000, function() {
            $(".content").fadeIn(10000);        
        });
    };

    setTimeout(function(){
        hideLoading();
    }, 1000);
});
```

May be it will help you.

Comment: `setTimeout` ? Why ?

Comment: `$(document).ready(function()` works when DOM gets loaded , i want when the use clicks reload .

Comment: you can set loader on beforeunload

Comment: you have to set display block for loader from the CSS or using inline CSS, then using jQuery you should hide that loader after page load.

Comment: please add your code at jsfiddle or anywhere else, So I can update and make changes in that...